# Chamando uma mesma condição no código

Tags: java, android

```
//Função para verificar existência de conexão com a internet
public boolean verificaConexao() {  
    boolean conectado;  
    ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null  
        && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()  
        && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {  
            conectado = true;  
    } else {  
        conectado = false;  
    }  
    return conectado;  
}

// Verifica a conexao
if (verificaConexao() == true){
    // Chama a classe RequestTask
    new RequestTask().execute(ok);
} else {
    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tx.setText("Por favor, conecte-se a internet :(");
    ba.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Quero usar essa mesma condição em vários lugares do meu código. teria como fazer algo para chama-la ao invés de ter que escrever ela toda, toda vez que eu precisar dela?

Comment: Sem vc dar detalhes do que o `if` faz e dificil dar uma solucao, mas vc pode fazer uma funcao mesmo.

Comment: Se o que você precisa reutilizar é a condição do `if`, crie uma função que retorne um `boolean` e faça `if ( condicao() ) { ... }`. Se o que você quer reutilizar é o corpo, coloque-o na função e faça `if ( ... ) corpo()`. Se você quer reutilizar tudo, simplesmente crie uma função com o if e o corpo, e chame ela quando precisar. Se necessário, passe parâmetros para essa função, e lembre-se que ela não pode alterar variáveis locais no método chamador (se isso é necessário, em Java não há saída, a menos que você encapsule essas variáveis num objeto ou num array).

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que pretende. É criar uma função que retorne verdadeiro ou falso?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa especial que você quer fazer e não estamos entendendo (aí você precisa explicar melhor). Ou você ainda não sabe programar? O que todo mundo está entendendo é que você quer fazer algo bem básico na programação, precisamos saber se este é o caminho para ajudarmos você. Caso contrário a pergunta será fechada por não estar clara.

Comment: editado, da pra entender agora? :)

Comment: Se o que deseja não é o que eu respondi, então ainda não deu pra entender.

Comment: Você mudou a pergunta mais uma vez e continua não dando para entender o que você quer. Se quer usar o método `verificaConexao()` em vários lugares, é só usar. Se quer que todo o `if` todo (que alias tem uma condição redundante) esteja em uma método, coloque ele em um método e chame onde você precisa. É igual ao que você já fez com a outra condição. Se ainda não é isto, dê um jeito de explicar o que você quer. Ficar mudando os exemplos não está ajudando.

Comment: tentei com um método mais que não estava funcionando por causa do valor que não era booleano e sim string, @bigown vlw ae :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
public void conexao() {
    if (verificaConexao() == true){
        // Chama a classe RequestTask
        new RequestTask().execute(site);
    } else {
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tx.setText("Por favor, conecte-se a internet :(");
        ba.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

// Verifica a conexao
conexao();
```

Comment: Para que o `return` se ele está null? Não seria melhor definir `public void conexao()`?

Comment: obrigado @GustavoCinque, porque não sabia :S

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

O mais educado é que vc separe as responsabilidades aí.

```
Predicate<ConnectivityManager> connectionValidator = 
                c -> null != c.getActiveNetworkInfo() 
                    && c.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() 
                    && c.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
```

Aí, no cara que você for validar a conexão, você manipula os atributos e repassa.

```
ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  

if (connectionValidator.test(conectivtyManager)){
    new RequestTask().execute(ok);
} else {
    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tx.setText("Por favor, conecte-se a internet :(");
    ba.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Claro que aqui supus que você irá validar apenas a nível da classe. Se for algo que for ser usado ao longo do sistema, é melhor que você crie uma classe que implemente Predicate e deixe o código lá. Se estiver usando injeção de dependências um tanto melhor.

Comment: Convém referir que [Predicate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Predicate.html) só está disponível a partir da API24 e que requer java 8.

Comment: É um ponto, jovem. Esqueci-me de comentar, bem como que optei por escrever usando expressão Lambda.